# It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

I am using mongo 4.0, mongoose 4.13.17, express 4.16.13.
I try to connect my angular application to Mongo DB via api call.
On hitting the browser I find the error It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.
I understand http request is deprecated following the 3.6 release.
Can anyone help me out how can I connect.

Comment: Your Angular app has to communicate with your Express server app (using `fetch`, `socket.io`, WebSocket, whatever), and your Express server app will communicate with the MongoDB server. You can't communicate from the Angular app with the MongoDB server directly (nor would you want to, because it comes with all kinds of security issues).

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that mongodb is running before you start making api calls.
Using postman, insert and retrieve documents from your database. This way, you can be sure that your API is working.